# Creating a conditional statement to correspond with scanner input

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements

I'm developing a program for class.

I need to read the user's input using the scanner class. 
I then need to pass this data through to an array list with a while loop.
Within my while loop, I need a conditional statement to check whether a 0 or a negative number is entered.
If the user inputs a negative number or a 0, the loop ends and the code moves onto the next process...

**The problems I'm currently facing are:**

-All my input values are not being processed

-I have to enter the value 0 3 times to exit the loop

-0 is being passed through to my array list which I do not want

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class questionAvg3
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

Scanner input_into = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> collector = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("Enter 0 or a negative number to end input");
System.out.println("Enter a positive integer to populate the arraylist");


    while ((input_into.nextInt() !=0) || (input_into.nextInt() < 0)){
    System.out.println("Type another int or exit");
        collector.add(input_into.nextInt());
    }

    int minValue = collector.get(0);
    int maxValue = collector.get(0); 
    //int avgValue = collector.get(0);
    //int total = 0;
    for(Integer i: collector){
        if( i < minValue) minValue = i;
        if( i > maxValue) maxValue = i;
    }       
    System.out.println("The max value int is: " + maxValue);
    System.out.println("The min value int is: " + minValue);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
while ((input_into.nextInt() !=0) || (input_into.nextInt() < 0)){
System.out.println("Type another int or exit");
    collector.add(input_into.nextInt());
}
```

The reason you have to enter the 0 three times is because you are calling `input_into.nextInt()` 3 times!

This means that your program is waiting for an integer, evaluating the input based on your comparison, then doing that again, and finally one last time for your `collector.add()`.

I think that it's important for you to understand how to use comparison operators a bit better.

For example, when you say `(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || (input_into.nextInt() < 0)` You are literally saying the number is less than zero or greater than zero.
Since your sentinal value is any number that is <= zero, you only want to continue if your input is GREATER than zero. This gives you the following

```
    int input = input_into.nextint();
    while (input > 0){
       System.out.println("Type another int or exit");
       collector.add(input);
       input = input_into.nextint();
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For both helping me understand better and solve my problem.

Comment: @AnthonyJ I would encourage you to alter the loop to what I have above, it is a bit easier to read and actually better on performance because you are doing one less comparison per iteration than your initial loop setup.

Answer (score 5):

```
while ((input_into.nextInt() !=0) || (input_into.nextInt() < 0)){
    System.out.println("Type another int or exit");
        collector.add(input_into.nextInt());
    }
```

That really needs 3 integers to pass on. Because `nextInt` look for the next input value always.

What you need is

```
int input = input_into.nextInt();
  while ((input !=0) || (input < 0)){
        System.out.println("Type another int or exit");
            collector.add(input);
            input = input_into.nextInt();
        }
```

Comment: This creates an infinite loop. You should update your `input` at the end of your while loop.

Comment: I've implemented this, but I'm now stuck in an infinite loop of printing "Type another int or exit"

Comment: @AnthonyJ Just add `input = input_into.nextInt();` to the end of your while loop.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ to bad i do not get rep for it. :p

Answer (score 0):

use a variable inside the loop and use it to test the loop continuation condition

```
  int variable=input.nextInt(); //get initial input

  while (variable<=0)
    {
        //get next input
        variable=input.nextInt();
    }//end while
```

This will loop till the input is <=0